# NGXS: Testing Asynchronous Actions: Automatic subscription doesn't work

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, store, ngxs

**from official website NGXS**

[image]

1. I write unit tests for NGXS store(Jasmine + Karma, angular 2)
2. In NGXS store in Asynchronous Actions(it's like Effect in NGRX) we don't subscribe inside - we just return observable. And it's fine, because the automatics subscription works.
3. BUT when I launch my tests, the automatic subscription on Asynchronous Actions(EFFECTS) - just doesn't work. As the result - test failed.
4. To sum up - I can't test Asynchronous Actions NGXS
5. What I have already  tried : 
   1) I wrote like in the official website NGXS(in the picture) 2)I tried it(done()) construction, 3) I tried actions$.subscribe() construction.
6. It works when I make manually - .subscribe() in the Action - but it's problem, because it have to work without this
7. This is link to official page: https://www.ngxs.io/recipes/unit-testing (topic : Testing Asynchronous Actions)
   Please, help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example from the official page works correctly. If you stub some function from an action, which returns Observable, try embedding the delay inside your stub function. 
For example,

`stubFunc: () => {
    return timer(0).pipe( ... );
}`

Comment: THANK you very much !
You right, subscribtion works correctly, but it was returning undefined
I suppose stub function just didn't return stub parameters
In stub function I changed: 
return of(stub)
<->
return timer(0).pipe(mergaMap(()=>of(stub)))
And it works fine!
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

THE ANSWER

```
`
// it doesn't work for me:
myStubFunction: () => {
    return of(stubResult);
};
// the solution was
myStubFunction: () => {
    return timer(0).pipe(mergMap(()=>of(stubResult)));
};
`
```